# Program that receives a list and returns a tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

Hi I need help to create a program that receives a list and returns a tuple with the following guidelines:

- The first value of the tuple is the same of the first in the list.
- The second element has to be greater than the first one but with
  the shortest distance between them.
- Has to be a smaller value
  than the second one, but with the maximum distance between them.

For example:

```
list=[12, 6, 30, 25, 40, 3, 7]
```

result:

```
tuple= (12, 25, 3, 6, 7, 30, 40)
```

Comment: You are asking two different things. To convert to tuple a simple `tuple(my_list)` will do. But what you want is an algorithm to order elements in a specific way. You should try solving that. It's not a simple list to tuple conversion.

Comment: OP need to change the title of the question.

Comment: Can OP please add more explanation for point 3.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function [tuple()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tuple-function) for the desired outcome

```
my_list = [1,2]
print(tuple(my_list))
```

Output: `(1, 2)`

I have added an answer for the list to tuple conversion. For the algorithm, you can generate the new list and convert it to a tuple with this function.

Answer (score 0):

I think I reached what you want.
The Code I created:

```
def target(inputs):
    output = []

    output.append(inputs[0])
    inputs = inputs[1:]

    # The Second Value
    second = [x for x in inputs if x > output[0]]
    new = []
    for num in second:
        new.append(num - output[0])
    
    output.append(second[new.index(min(new))])
    inputs.remove(second[new.index(min(new))])

    for i in sorted(inputs):
        output.append(i)

    return tuple(output)
```

I tested it and it is clear of bugs

I ran it with your list.

```
inputs=[12, 6, 30, 25, 40, 3, 7]
print(target(inputs))
```

and this is the output

```
(12, 25, 3, 6, 7, 30, 40)
```

I also tested it with this list

```
inputs=[19, 21, 25, 100, 8, 13]
```

and the output is

```
(19, 21, 8, 13, 25, 100)
```